# How to change Text button Color when I write something in the Text Field

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want text button to show grey color when text field is empty and green when some text is entered into the text field. How would i do that??

```
  TextField (),
  TextButton(
       child: Text("Press Here"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)){
                          return Colors.green;}
                        return Colors.grey;
                       }
                     ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: `TextField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
  decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.orange, filled: true),
)`

Answer (score 1):

check you input text is empty?

```
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  bool isTextEmpty;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: textEditingController,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              if (value.length > 0) {
                isTextEmpty = true;
              } else {
                isTextEmpty = false;
              }
            });
          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Press Here"),
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
              if (isTextEmpty) {
                return Colors.green;
              }
              return Colors.grey;
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `TextButton`'s background color to a variable and then change the variable's value when `TextField's` value changes occurred in the `onChange` callback.

Checkout this sample code:

```dart
  Color primaryColor = Colors.grey;
```

```
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TextField(
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    primaryColor = val.isNotEmpty ? Colors.green : Colors.grey;
                  });
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey.shade50,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: primaryColor),
                  child: Text("Submit"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```